# Linguex in sciposter

Tags: fontsize, linguistics, linguex, sciposter

I am trying to create a linguistic poster with sciposter but the glossed examples appear in wrong fontsize. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a0,28pt]{sciposter}

\usepackage{linguex}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
Normal text

\exg. This looks too small \\  
This looks too small \\  
Translation looks ok  

\ex. That looks ok

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues: the `sciposter` class defines `\normalsize` in a wrong way, so the `\@selfnt` macro of `cgloss4e.sty` issues `\@currsize`, which isn't updated by `sciposter`: chaos ensues.

The second issue is due to `cgloss4e` explicitly issuing `\rmfamily`.

Here's a fixed version:

```
\documentclass[a0,28pt]{sciposter}

\usepackage{linguex}

\makeatletter
\def\@selfnt{}
\makeatother
\let\eachwordone=\normalfont
\let\eachwordtwo=\normalfont
\let\eachwordthree=\normalfont

\begin{document}

\show\rmfamily

\section{Introduction}
Normal text

\exg. This looks too small \\
This looks too small \\
Translation looks ok

\ex. That looks ok

\end{document}
```

I made `\@selfnt` into a no op, as there's no hope to make it work in the intended way; there should be no problem, anyway.

[image]